# How to load next/previous Cell from UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, nsarray, cell

I have saved values in a NSArray. If I click on a cell in the tableView it loads the Values from the Array in the fields. What if I want to load the values from the next/previous cell in the fields when I click a Button?

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. It may help if you post the code you're trying, and what isn't working with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unclear so I'm answering it the best I can.

You have the indexPath.row of the cell you clicked on right?

You can access the previous cell using:

```
UITableViewCell *previousCell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row - 1 inSection:indexPath.section]];
```

Similarly for the next cell:

```
UITableViewCell *nextCell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section]];
```

I assume you'll handle all the cases where your current row is the first/last row so you don't want to try and access rows before/after that.